# Spark Map action with custom function running in just one executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have this small piece of code:

```
sales = hive_context.table("inv_opt_test.store_sales")
sales1 = sales.rdd.map(lambda x : (str(x[0])+"-"+str(x[1]),x[3:]))
BaseStockLevel = sales1.groupByKey().map(lambda x: BigFunction(x)).cache()
```

Here after reading from Hive table I create keys `.map(lambda x : (str(x[0])+"-"+str(x[1]),x[3:]))`, followed by group of data with same keys `sales1.groupByKey()`. All these aforementioned stages run in multiple executor but at the map stage with custom function `.map(lambda x: BigFunction(x))` it runs just in one executor.

[image: Spark Application UI]
I believe it is not the case as in [Why is my Spark App running in only 1 executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014208/why-is-my-spark-app-running-in-only-1-executor) . What could be probably reason of this behavior or am I missing any setting?

Comment: what is the size of your input?

Comment: 12 Million+ rows